# Parse.com Hosted App: Dev vs Prod Switch

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I have two Parse apps, MyApp and MyAppDev (made according to the Parse.com docs - https://parse.com/docs/hosting_guide#devprod), which use some external API and share the same underlying codebase.

Is there a way I can add an If statement switch so that the code uses a different API key for Prod vs Dev? i.e.

```
var key = '123';

if(PROD)
   key = '234';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could set a local environment variable on your dev machine, and then in your app try to import the DEV env variable. If successful, use the key for DEV, and if not, use the key for PROD.

Comment: Thanks although not sure how to do this with Parse.com hosting - I don't have access to environment variables... but maybe Parse Configs are right to use here

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the application Id in a custom config script:

```
var key = '123';

if(Parse.applicationId === PROD_APP_ID)
   key = '234';
```